# C# Convert.ToDouble Input string was not in a correct format in Windows service

Tags: c#, service, double

I have been running a console app for the past few weeks with no issues.
However as soon as I converted the app to a windows service Ive been getting errors where I convert string to doubles using the Convert.ToDouble() function. Here I get the error message "Input string was not in a correct format".

Other posts mainly refers to using culture info such as Convert.ToDouble(string, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).

But my code has been running for weeks without any issues, why would running the same code as a service make a difference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A service may run with a different user account than the console, and therefore may have a different culture

Answer (score 1):

Your service probably runs under a different user (this is the most common problem (and answer regarding windows services) with a different culture.

To quickly test this - set your service to start as You. If my theory is correct it should run ok. *Do not* solve the problem this way. Instead change back to the user you should use and verify you get the problem back. Now you Know it is user related.

Then do what the interwebs propose with InvariantCulture to solve the problem properly.